# Microsoft Azure Subnetting

Tags: azure, azure-networking

Im trying to simulate a real life environment on Azure, and I wonder if its even possible.

Ive read through MS documentation and Im a bit lost.

I wish to simulate a 2 tier network with  firewall separating the two tiers (like pfsense).

However, routing might be my downfall. Is it possible to simulate these parameters:

**Node 1:**
Ubuntu desktop
IP: 192.168.1.10
Gateway: 192.168.1.254

**FIREWALL:**
Pfsense
IP1: 192.168.1.254
IP2: 192.168.2.254

**Server 1:**
Ubuntu server
IP: 192.168.2.10

The idea here is to simulate a user accesing a server through a fw.

As far as my test went - not so well.. I think the downfall is the fact that azure routes are external to the VM and im required to route between subnets (so i cant have the pfsense a default gateway for the VMs).

Id appreciate ideas :)

Answer (score 1):

What you have to do is to override Azure default network routes by using custom routes.

So your Pfsense box would be the next hop in your route table, and then you can apply this route table to the subnet so that all traffic is enforced through your virtual appliance while also enabling IP Forwarding to make sure your NVA can forward the traffic.

Said that, although Azure supports VMs with multiple NICs, it doesn't support a single VM to have NICs configured to multiple VNETs, so as long as your IP Addresses are within a single VNET you're fine.

References:

[Virtual network traffic routing](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/virtual-networks-udr-overview)

[Create a user-defined route](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/create-user-defined-route-portal)

[Virtual appliance scenario](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/virtual-network-scenario-udr-gw-nva)

[Create and manage a Windows virtual machine that has multiple NICs](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/multiple-nics)

Answer (score 0):

> I think the downfall is the fact that azure routes are external to the
>   VM and im required to route between subnets

You are right, Azure will route network traffic between subnets in the same Virtual network.

Are you want to associate firewall to subnet?

If I understand it correctly, we can create Azure network security group, and **associate NSG to a subnet**, then use that NSG to limit it.
[image]

Comment: Hi, following up on your reply and the one before you. I had UDR assigned, but I also had NSGs and my UDR lacked a specific route. Evidently i solved my issues with clean slate (no NSGs for inbetween subnets, proper UDR routings, and one mroe important rule - NEVER, and i mean NEVER! alter VM intern routings).. Thanks!